# PHP API creation software, database schema

Tags: php, mysql, database, api, schema

I'm creating a software that lets you create any REST API you want, online.

For example you want to create API that shares a list of car models/manufacturers of 20th century, so you would need fields like: color, model, manufacturer, and "unlimited" amount of other fields.

Any registered user, can create "unlimited" amount of APIs, that discloses "unlimited" amount of data (to be specific: rows od data in format: id|color|model|manufacturer|and so on).

The question is **how to store this kind of data**.

I created a working mockup that uses 4 tables: **feeds, rows, columns and values**

But this leads to:

- complex joins
- limited functionality due to some processing must be done on the PHP site
- need of additional abstraction layer

So **my next idea is to create a separate database** (which would be partitioned horizontally if needed), like **myproject_data**.

When creating an API, the table would be created in myproject_data with appropriate name.

This solution would eliminate abstraction layer that is needed to process data (columns, rows, values, feeds) to usable data (properly formatted rows populated with data).

As far as I am concerned about performance issues I may expect from using hundreds of tables, I believe that performance loss would not be as big as when using complex joins and using only 4 tables with hundreds of thousands of records.
Additionaly that would eliminate additional abstraction layer.

**What do you think ?**

Comment: why dont you store objects together with metadata that describe the object?

Comment: you mean like serialized (json?) objects  ?

Comment: yes i meant serialized objects.

Comment: but I need to perform queries with: order by, limit, offset, with option of limit fields. storing serialized objects would make it very difficult.

Comment: Maybe look at mongo or couchdb. SQL database may not be the best possible option.

Comment: but then, any api that user created, would have to be a separate collection ? do i get it right ?